# Unable to get response from rest web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am trying to create a restful web service in java. Whenever I am clicking on the link which calls the web service I see following page-

[image]

I am referring JavaTPoint for this.

This is how my project looks like-

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"   
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
        <param-value>com.javatpoint.rest</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="localhost:9989/rest/files/txt">Download Text File</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**FileDownloadService.java**

```
package com.javatpoint.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/files")
public class FileDownloadService {

    @GET
    @Path("/txt")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String getFile() {
        String msg="<?xml version='1.0'?>"
                + "<hello>AAAA</hello>";
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Can you try localhost:9989/<contextroot>/rest/files/txt

Comment: @SanketD still getting same error..also tried changing context root to rest and leaving link like "localhost:9989/rest/files/txt"..but issue is still there!

Comment: Are you just missing the http:// in the link?

Comment: Can you past the log of application server here?

Comment: I am getting following error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Comment: are you using maven?

Answer (score 1):

Check with prefix with http://
eg: http://localhost:9989/WSRest/rest/files/txt
OR

http://127.0.0.1:9989/WSRest/rest/files/txt